# OSGi public bundlecontext

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

Is it dangerous to change the bundlecontext of a bundle to public?

The reason why I would like to do is, is to access the Context from a different package.

Of course a workaround would be to pass the context as a parameter when instantiate an object. But if it wouldn't be too dangerous to make the context public, this way would be more easy.

Comment: You mean storing it in a public variable? Where would you make it public? In the activator? Do you mean a public static variable?

Comment: Yes, I would like to store it in a public static variable. At the moment it is stored in a proteced static variable, which works fine. The question is not if it would work (it works, I tried it already) but the question is, if it is save to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not store BundleContext in a public static variable for several reasons.

From the Javadoc of BundleContext:

> The BundleContext object is only valid during the execution of its context bundle; that is, during the period from when the context bundle is in the STARTING, STOPPING, and ACTIVE bundle states. [...]

If you do so, you might forget to set the static variable when the bundle stops. In that case others can access the bundle context when it is in *marked for removal* state. In this state, others are stille wired to this bundle.

> A BundleContext object is generally for the private use of its associated bundle and is not meant to be shared with other bundles in the OSGi environment.

By assigning the BundleContext to a static variable, you let others to access it. Well, if the class is in a non-exported package, it is harder, but still possible to get it.

> A Bundle can be adapted to its BundleContext. In order for this to succeed, the caller must have the appropriate AdminPermission[bundle,CONTEXT] if the Java Runtime Environment supports permissions.

If you accidently take this public static variable into a class that is in an exported package, others can access it without permission checks.

*Issue if the package is exported and imported*

Imagine that you have package A and B. Package A is exported but also imported. It can happen that classes from package B will see package A classes from a different bundle. In that case classes from package B will use the bundle context of a different bundle.

All of the examples are special ones above but they show how easily you can get into trouble if you store your BundleContext in a static variable. If you are careful, you will not cause any trouble, but remember, you might not be the only one, who changes the code of the project.

In general, it is not a good practice to use static variables (except constants) or functions, especially in OSGi. If you want to use any of them, it is time to ask if you should refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it would be a god idea to store the BundleContext in a static variable. Better create your classes from the activator start method and inject the BundleContext there.

Comment: Could you tell me what could happen if I did? Is it just bad practice or will there be some bad behavior?

Comment: The big problem is that you then tie all your classes to the static call. This makes testing using mocks harder. Not sure if there is a problem at runtime too.